MySQL Workbench error "name is not activatable"
I'm working with Arch Linux using MariaDB through LAMPP, whenever I use MySQL workbench and try to connect to my local database I get the following:

Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' to the MySQL server at 127.0.0.1:3306: The name is not activatable.

The reason why I mention that I'm using MariaDB is that I get this error when I test the connection:

Incompatible/nonstandard server version or protocol detected (10.4.32) <== MariaDB's version

I can still continue despite the error, and it shows that it successfully connected to the database, however, whenever trying to run a SQL Script, it can't connect to the database.
I've tried: using another user, reinstalling MySQL workbench, reinstalling XAMPP. Yet all of these attempts were in vain.
Is there a method to solve this whilst keeping MariaDB?

For anyone wondering, I did end up resolving this issue, turns out I didn't have a keyring provider installed in my system.
Installing something like "gnome-keyring" fixed the issue!
